# QMake - How to add and use a variable into the .pro file

Tags: qt, qmake

I have a qmake file generated by Qt creator.
I am modifying it but I do not manage to understand how to create a variable.

For example, I want to declare the library MYPATH as I did here:

```
MYPATH = /lib/aaa/bbb
unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L$(MYPATH)
```

When I run qmake I find in the generated makefile

```
LIBS = ....... -L$(MYPATH) .....
```

But the MYPATH variable is not declared anywhere.

Does anyone know how to declare such a variable properly?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

QMake uses [its own syntax for variable references](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-advanced-usage.html#variables).

- `VAR = foobar` => Assign value to variable when qmake is run
- `$$VAR` => QMake variable's value at the time qmake is run
- `$${VAR}` => QMake variable's value at the time qmake is run (identical but enclosed to separate from surrounding text)
- `$(VAR)` => Contents of an Environment variable at the time Makefile (not qmake) is run
- `$$(VAR)` =>Contents of an Environment variable at the time qmake (not Makefile) is run

Try it like this

```
MYPATH = /lib/aaa/bbb
unix:!macx:!symbian: LIBS += -L$${MYPATH}
```

Comment: Not to forget $$(VAR) for Contents of an Environment variable at the time qnake (not Makefile!) is run

Comment: So, what is the subtle difference between `$$VAR` and `$${§VAR}`? I've staring at each explanation and can't find a single difference... o.0

Comment: @AdriC.S. I believe they are exactly the same. `$${VAR}` exists to resolve cases like `lib$$VERSION.dll`. without putting it between curly braces `lib$${VERSION}.dll`, the variable will not resolve because it is not followed by a space or a slash.

Comment: If would be nice if you add what does it actually mean 'at time of qmake' and 'at time of makefile'. I don't know myself, I thought we work with qmake and never worry about makefile.

Comment: ${} for build-in variables of QMake, such as ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME}.

Answer (score 18):

Other useful variable type:  `$$[...]`
This means "configuration option that were set when Qt was built"

Example:

```
message($$[QT_INSTALL_BINS])
```

This gives:

```
C:\Qt\Qt5.0.2\5.0.2\msvc2010_opengl\bin
```