# qmake - how to use variables in another pri file

Tags: qt, qmake

I'm porting Visual Studio QT projects to linux.
Each project has .pro file, and solution has a main pro file including each project's pro files.
I'd like to declare common makefile variables to share with each pro file.
I made common.pri and included it at the first line in each project's pro file,
but it can't read common.pri's variables.
How can I use another pri file to share common variables?

Comment: This can help, probably: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754218/qmake-add-a-variable-into-the-pro-file

Comment: Are you sure the pri file is included in all projects (ie do they find the prifile)?  Do you use relative paths in variables? As is the question is unclear.