# QT pro file: DESTDIR is empty

Tags: qt

I do not define `DESTDIR` anywhere.

```
message($$DESTDIR)
```

prints empty string.

Is there a way to know path to the target binary?

Answer (score 0):

In `message()` need to use different notation for some reason:

```
message(DESTDIR: ($$DESTDIR))
```

I had such problem today. Solved only by looking at qmake .pro files examples in Qt [mailing list](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/interest/2015-May/017008.html). Another possible problem - [clue variables](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-language.html#variables):

```
# ${VAR} notation allows to append the contents of the variable to another value
# without separating the two with a space
isEmpty(DESTDIR): DESTDIR = $${IDE_BUILD_TREE}/lib/qtcreator/plugins
```

Without such notation I got empty `DESTDIR` variable. If `DESTDIR` is not set, I believe binary stays in build dir.

Another useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7754767/630169

Comment: Different? You use the same $$DESTDIR as in the question. And the thing you posted here is not an answer at all. Please remove it.

Comment: @AlexanderDyagilev Not same: `message(($$DESTDIR))`

Comment: These additional () means nothing. It just prints them.

Comment: I do not remember exact problem - it did not work, think message() - qmake function, `($$DESTDIR)` - variable. Simple `$$DESTDIR` did not work.

Comment: I've just tried on a new project. My variant prints "", yours prints "()". It does not print the directory in both cases.