# Add an extension in a .pro variable

Tags: qt, qt5, qmake

I'm trying to print a message with QMake but I have problems with extensions:

```
lib_name = $$1
message("test1: $$MYPATH/$$lib_name/src/$$lib_name.pri");
message("test2: $$MYPATH/$$lib_name/src/$$lib_name");
```

For some reason, `test1` doesn't print the correct path. It just prints the path until `src/`. But, `test2` is ok. It prints everything until the value in `$$1`.

Any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QMake supports variables (objects) with members that can be used using the dot `.` operator e.g. `target.path` for [INSTALLS](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#installs). So, in your case, `$$lib_name.pri` means that you're accessing the member `pri` of `lib_name` which doesn't exist so there's no output.

You need to enclose variables in curly braces for QMake to distinguish them from the surrounding text i.e. `$${lib_name}.pri`.

Example:

```
message("test1: $$MYPATH/$$lib_name/src/$${lib_name}.pri");
#                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

For more examples of objects, see [Adding Custom Target](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-custom-targets) and [Adding Compilers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html#adding-compilers) sections of QMake's [Advanced Usage](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html) page.

Here's another relevant SO thread: [QMake - How to add and use a variable into the .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754218/qmake-how-to-add-and-use-a-variable-into-the-pro-file)