# Setting environment variables in qmake

Tags: qt, variables, environment-variables, qt5, qmake

With the following dummy qmake syntax I am trying to set an environment variable and then check it later:

```
MY_VAR = true
message("A")
defined(MY_VAR){
    message("B")
}
```

The unintuitive part for me is that upon running this qmake script, only **"A"** is outputted to the console and not **"B"**;

So what is the correct way of setting an environment variable in qmake?

Comment: Note: the .pro is only used when the program is compiled, not when it is executed, so I don't see the point of environment variables. If you want to configure something in the build then use DEFINE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [QMake - How to add and use a variable into the .pro file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754218/qmake-how-to-add-and-use-a-variable-into-the-pro-file)

Comment: Nope. It does not say how to test a variable in .pro file or in code.

Answer (score 0):

To check for *variable* existence you must invoke

```
defined(MY_VAR, var): message(...)
```

BTW. this is a regular qmake variable, not environment variable.